# jquery-nice-select with vue.js is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, jquery-plugins, vue.js

I use this library: https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select

And include this plugin in file `bootstrap.js`:

```
require('jquery-nice-select');
```

Than I use in the application file `app.js`

**app.js:**

```
require('./bootstrap');

// ... code

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    components: {
      App
    },
    template: '<app></app>',
    mounted() {
        $(document).find('select').niceSelect();
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

Config for build my project `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/vendors.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/style.scss', 'public/css')
    .extract(
        [
            'vue',
            'vue-resource',
            'vue-router',
            'vue-scrollto',
            'vue-meta'
        ],
        'public/js/vue.js'
    )
    .extract(
        [
            'jquery',
            'bootstrap-sass',
            'jquery-nice-select',
            'owl.carousel',
            'jquery-parallax.js',
        ],
        'public/js/vendor.js'
    )
    .autoload({
        'jquery': ['$', 'jquery', 'jQuery', 'window.jQuery'],
        'tether': ['window.Tether', 'Tether'],
    })
;
```

However, when you try to use the niceSelect plugin, the following error occurs:

> vue.js:484 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError:
>   $(...).niceSelect is not a function"

and this:

> TypeError: $(...).niceSelect is not a function

I do not understand where to look and what I'm doing is not right? At me such problem has arisen only with the given plug-in, earlier all always was connected and worked correctly.

**P.S.** Note, the error is not that the function is not declared, but that it is not a function. And yes the connection of all JS in the public is done normally:

```
<!-- code -->
<script src="{{ mix('/js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/vue.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

**UPD:** By the way, the same error appears in directives.

```
export default {
    directives: {
        niceSelect: {
            update(el) {
                const $  = window.$;
                $(el).niceSelect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you load the plugin?

Comment: Yes, plugin load with `require("jquery-nice-select")`

Comment: That's not how you load the plugin. Did you try following the instructions? https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select#usage

Comment: This plugin packing with all vendors js library via Webpack, and then load with all js library. I don't follow instruction because niceSelect install from NPM repository, but in fact this is the same way. And if you see the error, it is writing there "`niceSelect is not a function`", not "`niceSelect is not defined`"

Comment: Try entering this into a JavaScript console: `({}).f();` What does the error say?

Comment: `VM24251:1 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).f is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to update your question with your solution 
https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select/issues/60

From myself I can say that I had same error `niceSelect is not a function` (with Yii2 Framework, but it is not necessary), the reason was that jQuery was included twice, resulting page source (in browser) was like this:

- css
- jquery.js
- nice-select.js
- niceSelect initialization function
- main document content
- another jquery.js

I just modified code to make last item gone, and it works.

So I advise to review page's resulting  source code (in browser)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have some link to jQuery. I left one and it worked!

You can add `import` or `require` in `.js` file

```
require('jquery-nice-select');
```

or

```
import 'jquery-nice-select/js/jquery.nice-select';
```

**I used Webpack without any framework**